Unable to join a new Samba Active Directory from Windows 11 and Linux
I have a network with Windows Server 2003 Active Directory server and Windows 11 computers. My plan is to replace Windows Server 2003 with Fedora Linux Server Edition - fedora 40. I could test it with Windows 11 clients and one Fedora Linux 40 client.
The old realm is SONCANALS. The new realm is SCNG.
I followed guide of the Fedora Magazine.
Configurations

The server IP is10.216.1.16 and domain is scng.educaib

Server hostname is l1.scng.educaib

samba.conf:
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
# Global parameters
[global]
        dns forwarder = 1.1.1.1
        netbios name = L1
        realm = SCNG.EDUCAIB
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = SCNG
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        ldap server require strong auth = no 

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/scng/scripts
        read only = No


Kerberos config:
# cat /etc/krb5.conf.d/samba-dc 
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = SCNG.EDUCAIB
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
SCNG.EDUCAIB = {
        default_domain = SCNG
}

[domain_realm]
        l1.scng.educaib = SCNG.EDUCAIB


/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/custom.conf:
[Resolve]
DNSStubListener=no
Domains=scng.educaib
DNS=10.216.1.16



I have one machine with Fedora 40 which I use to test samba. When I test all is fine (section "Testing" in tutorial guide). When I run realm discover, I get only old realm, not the new one:
realm discover -v
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.soncanals
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.216.1.2
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.216.1.10
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.216.1.4
 * Successfully discovered: soncanals
soncanals
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: SONCANALS
  domain-name: soncanals
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-common
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd-ad
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools

In Windows, when I try to join to SCNG, I am prompted for administrator logon, but when I put credentials it takes too long and it leaves dialog.

How can I triage the problem here? For example, which logs can I see (I have a lot in /var/log/samba/). My samba version i 4.20.5.
My priority is to join new domain and login to Windows as regular user in this domain. I discard for the moment sharing directories.
Edit (2024-11-11): The tests in Fedora Magazine guide are passed OK:
Testing
Connectivity test
$ smbclient -L localhost -N
Anonymous login successful

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        sysvol          Disk      
        netlogon        Disk      
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.21.1)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available

$ smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator -c 'ls'
Password for [SCNG\Administrator]:
  .                                   D        0  Thu Oct 31 10:17:05 2024
  ..                                  D        0  Thu Oct 31 10:17:05 2024

                15663104 blocks of size 1024. 12979380 blocks available

DNS Test
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.scng.educaib.
_ldap._tcp.scng.educaib has SRV record 0 100 389 l1.scng.educaib.
$ host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.scng.educaib.
_kerberos._udp.scng.educaib has SRV record 0 100 88 l1.scng.educaib.
$ host -t A l1.scng.educaib.
l1.scng.educaib has address 10.216.1.16

Kerberos test
$  kinit administrator
Password for administrator@SCNG.EDUCAIB: 
ladmin@l1:~$ klist
Ticket cache: KCM:1000
Default principal: administrator@SCNG.EDUCAIB

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/11/24 10:15:10  11/11/24 20:15:10  krbtgt/SCNG.EDUCAIB@SCNG.EDUCAIB
        renew until 18/11/24 10:15:06


ActiveDirectory Windows NT server Active Directory was introduced with Windows 2000. We are now at Windows Server 2025. I sincerely hope this is an error and you are not actually running Windows NT...

@Massimo Yes, my fault. It is Windows Server 2003. I corrected the text

There is something noticeably wrong. The server at 10.216.1.16 should not return ANY details about the other domain. That's because you are only getting the new domain up and running. It should be documented that the endpoint is using only 10.216.1.16 and DNS and not others.

@GregAskew What do you mean? In other machine (not the server) if I run realm discover, then I would receive SCNG as workgroup also? Is it true? What's wrong with that? How can I see SCNG domain from client computers?

Configure your Samba Active Directory Domain Controller/DNS Server using the Windows tool from your workstation and tell us what zones you see. https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DNS_Administration

@GregAskew But why in linux machines, realm discover does not detect the new domain SCNG? Thanks for the appointment.

The problem is that the server and clients needs to be in the same domain. As we need Full Qualified Domain, we need SCNG.LOCAL instead just SCNG or SCNG.EDUCAIB.
In my case the Samba server has hostname l1.scng.local and static IP 10.216.1.16. My gateway is 10.216.1.1

On the server side, follow the instruccions on the guide. I changed the samba-tool domain provision step to this:
samba-tool domain provision --server-role=dc --use-rfc2307 --interactive

because it allows to type admin password interactively. My configuration is:
 # cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
 # Global parameters
 [global]
         dns forwarder = 1.1.1.1
         netbios name = L1
         realm = SCNG.LOCAL
         server role = active directory domain controller
         workgroup = SCNG
         idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

 [sysvol]
         path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
         read only = No

 [netlogon]
         path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/scng.local/scripts
         read only = No

  # cat /etc/krb5.conf.d/samba-dc
  [libdefaults]
          default_realm = SCNG.LOCAL
          dns_lookup_realm = false
          dns_lookup_kdc = true

  [realms]
         SCNG.LOCAL = {
            default_domain = SCNG
         }

  [domain_realm]
         l1.scng.local = SCNG.LOCAL

Other important configuration is:
 # cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/custom.conf 
 [Resolve]
 DNSStubListener=no
 Domains=scng.local
 DNS=10.216.1.16

 root@l1:/home/ladmin# cat /etc/hostname 
 l1.scng.local

 root@l1:/home/ladmin# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
 # This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
 # Do not edit.
 #
 # This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
 # /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
 #
 # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
 # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
 #
 # Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
 # through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
 # different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
 #
 # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
 # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

 nameserver 10.216.1.16
 nameserver 10.216.1.4
 nameserver 1.1.1.1
 search scng.local

The 10.216.1.4 is the my DNS of my local network. It is optional to put it. I replace 8.8.8.8 with 1.1.1.1 in the Fedora Guide.

On the client side, we need to set client DNS as the server IP. This DNS setting is crucial. In my case, the client has static IP 10.216.1.192. So I need to configure network with gateway 10.216.1.1 and DNS IP 10.216.1.16:

Set the hostname with the same network as server: hostnamectl hostname l192.scng.local

Setting the DNS server as Samba server. Repeat the same step as in server guide: create /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/custom.conf with content:
 [Resolve]
 DNSStubListener=no
 Domains=scng.local
 DNS=10.216.1.16



and run systemctl restart systemd-resolved. So the config is:
    cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    nameserver 10.216.1.16
    nameserver 10.216.1.16
    search scng.local



And then realm discover -v works (scng.local appears). And you could join in the client to scng.local: realm join scng.local. You could now login with <your username>@scng.local.
On windows clients, you just should change the domain to SCNG.LOCAL and everything works. User can login with username or username@scng.local in windows.

You almost definitely need to add the DNS records for your new domain. The fedora magazine has subheadings "DNS test" that show how to know if you did it right.

I updated the question: I passed OK all the test. You can see the output
